# Unable to display values from dataSnapshot in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a `RecyclerView` to showcase results from my `dataSnapshot`, but am unable to display the results correctly. Previously my JSON tree's structure was gameTimes > user_id > game > results but now the json tree has been shortened to gameTimes > game > results to allow for usernames to be found easier.

I have my `dataSnapshot` inside of my `GameInfoHolder` and inside the `setGameInfo` method. This may not be the best way to do this in practice but previously before the JSON tree change the results would work but the username's of the score's were not being shown beside the results. Not I just don't have any results at all. Below I have included a snippet of the data to display my problem.

I have included the structure of my JSON tree for reference.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

---

```
DatabaseReference hiscoreRef = rootRef.child("gameTimes").child(userID).child("game");
        Query hiscoreQuery = hiscoreRef.orderByChild("gameTime").limitToLast(10);
```

---

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<GameInfo> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<GameInfo>()
                .setQuery(hiscoreQuery, GameInfo.class)
                .build();
```

---

```
 firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<GameInfo, GameInfoHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GameInfoHolder gameInfoHolder, int i, @NonNull GameInfo gameInfo) {
                gameInfoHolder.setGameInfo(gameInfo);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public GameInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.firebase_item_file, parent, false);

                return new GameInfoHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

---

```
private class GameInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView score1;
    private TextView namename1;

    GameInfoHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        score1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.score1);
        name1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name1);

    }

    void setGameInfo(GameInfo gameInfo) {

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference hiscoreRef = rootRef.child("gameTimes").child("game");
        Query hiscoreQuery = hiscoreRef.orderByChild("gameTime").limitToFirst(10);
        hiscoreQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                int hiscore = 0;
                String uName = "";
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    hiscore = ds.child("gameTime").getValue(Integer.class);
                    uName = ds.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                }
                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(hiscore));
                String mScore1 = df.format(hiscore / 1000.0);
                score1.setText(mScore1);
                String mName1 = uName;
                name1.setText(mName1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
            }

        });
    }
 }
```

---

```
{
  "gameTimes" : {
    "game" : {
      "-LoHuG5ZY_e0Gzs3Phkh" : {
        "game_bank" : 0,
        "game_count" : 3,
        "gameTime" : 7194,
        "user_id" : "kzqG0GBns0bGLQdPeV70pO1k4BB2",
        "username" : "DataBoi"
      },
      "-LoHuMQFK7z2nN3kFb3F" : {
        "game_bank" : 0,
        "game_count" : 2,
        "gameTime" : 11784,
        "user_id" : "kzqG0GBns0bGLQdPeV70pO1k4BB2",
        "username" : "DataBoi"
      },
      "-LoHvWG32slt1hCXzaei" : {
        "game_bank" : 0,
        "game_count" : 3,
        "gameTime" : 20072,
        "user_id" : "kzqG0GBns0bGLQdPeV70pO1k4BB2",
        "username" : "DataBoi"
      },
      "-LoHvWHjhZJ3fqkbWmjy" : {
        "game_bank" : 0,
        "game_count" : 3,
        "gameTime" : 20072,
        "user_id" : "kzqG0GBns0bGLQdPeV70pO1k4BB2",
        "username" : "DataBoi"
      },
      "-LoHxnIM7KDce1rxr1MD" : {
        "game_bank" : 0,
        "game_count" : 2,
        "gameTime" : 11470,
        "user_id" : "T9psJTZhapPvXFuzo5NZ6bHG6xo1",
        "username" : "DataMan"
      }
    }
  },
  "userDetails" : {
    "T9psJTZhapPvXFuzo5NZ6bHG6xo1" : {
      "username" : "DataMan"
    },
    "kzqG0GBns0bGLQdPeV70pO1k4BB2" : {
      "username" : "DataBoi"
    }
  },
  "userInfo" : {
    "DataBoi" : {
      "kzqG0GBns0bGLQdPeV70pO1k4BB2" : {
        "date_of_birth" : "08/08/2018",
        "education" : "Master's",
        "exercise" : "1 - 2 Hours a Week",
        "forename" : "Data",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "surname" : "Boi",
        "username" : "DataBoi"
      }
    },
    "DataMan" : {
      "T9psJTZhapPvXFuzo5NZ6bHG6xo1" : {
        "date_of_birth" : "01/01/1019",
        "education" : "Yes",
        "exercise" : "10 Hours or more a Week",
        "forename" : "Data",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "surname" : "Man",
        "username" : "DataMan"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My expected results would be for the scoreboard to open and see > dataSnapshot of the first ten best gameTime's on the right hand side and the appropriate username (belonging to that sore) beside it on the left. The recycler view is set up fine for these views. The problem is just getting the results. 
Is it a problem with my JSON structure?

Comment: What did you expect this code to do with a recycler view? All it does is set the last result it gets from Firebase to a text view.  It doesn't seem to do anything with a RecyclerView or adapter yet.

Comment: I didn't include the adapter because I thought it was irrelevant to the problem. I'll update the code to make it more clear

Comment: Since your `hiscoreQuery...onDataChange(` doesn't add any data to an adapter, I don't see how a recycler view would show the data. What do you expect your code to do? Please note that it's typically easier to help if you reduce the scope if your question, not by removing code, but by reproducing the problem in isolation. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).